# Why does Dracula need to rest his days in consecrated earth?

Tags: dracula, undead, bram-stoker

Since consecrated earth, even the Transylvanian type, should be connected to the “sacred,” what are some possible reasons for  Bram Stoker to specify that Dracula needs this “holy soil” in order to rejuvenate during his daytime sleeps?

Comment: it does not make much sense, does it?

Comment: Because it makes it *extra creepy?*

Answer (score 0):

It is not that Dracula needs sacred soil, he needs soil that has sacred "memories", without it he is without some of his powers and cannot rest:

> At last I pulled open a heavy door which stood ajar, and found myself in an old, ruined chapel, which had evidently been used as a graveyard. The roof was broken, and in two places were steps leading to vaults, but the ground had recently been dug over, and the earth placed in great wooden boxes...

This passage shows the dirt being dug up and packaged into boxes. The broken roof and ruined chapel implies formerly sacred ground, though graveyards would be considered to be consecrated or sacred ground. I am not at all sure on how long a graveyard would be considered sacred after tumbling into ruins.

> Only at certain times can he have limited freedom. If he be not at the place whither he is bound, he can only change himself at noon or at exact sunrise or sunset. These things are we told, and in this record of ours we have proof by inference. Thus, whereas he can do as he will within his limit, when he have his earth-home, his coffin-home, his hell-home, the place unhallowed, as we saw when he went to the grave of the suicide at Whitby; still at other time he can only change when the time come. It is said, too, that he can only pass running water at the slack or the flood of the tide...  ... For it is not the least of its terrors that this evil thing is rooted deep in all good; in soil barren of holy memories it cannot rest.”

These lines indicate his earth home gives him some powers, shown to be shape-shifting, great strength etc. They also indicate that he was once a great and good man, who has worshipped god and needs that connection to god to thrive still.

You must remember when reading these stories that they were written during a time when belief in god was widespread and there wasn't much worse than the devil, so the corruption of good things to evil holds a special horror for believers. Thus it is a common theme in Victorian and more recent horror stories.